# UITextField does not get the text value of an Array

Tags: arrays, string, swift, uitextfield

I am using core data to save user input in an array. Until then the code works perfectly , the problem is the time to get some element of that array and put in UITextField as a text. The code has no errors , just does not work as it should.

```
@IBOutlet weak var quoteTextField: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var addQuote: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var deleteQuote: UIButton!

var bookArray: Array<AnyObject> = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()        

//Get the info on the CoreData
var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "BookArray")
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
bookArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!

if (bookArray.count != 0){
    var randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(bookArray.count)))
    quoteTextField.text = bookArray[randomIndex] as? String
   }
}
```

[image: DataModel]

And this is where I am saving the user input, which is located in another View Controller:

```
 @IBAction func saveOnData(sender: AnyObject) {

    var quoteInputText = quoteInput.text

    var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
    var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    var newQuote = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("BookArray", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! NSManagedObject

    newQuote.setValue(quoteInputText, forKey: "myFirstBook")

    context.save(nil)

    println(newQuote)

}
```

Comment: Can you please post the declaration of your BookArray entity? I will write down what's wrong with this code, but if you provide the declaration I will show you how to fix it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going line by line.

First you create a fetch request:

```
var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "BookArray")
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
```

Then you assign the result of your fetch request to the array called `bookArray`:

```
bookArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!
```

Function `executeFetchRequest` returns `[AnyObject]`. In your case it will return an array of `BookArray` entities `[BookArray]`.

So, when you call:

```
bookArray[randomIndex]
```

you get an instance of `BookArray`. Of course your conditional downcast to `String` will always fail ;)

Here is what you have to do:

1) Add the following class to your project:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(BookArray)
class BookArray:NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var myFirstBook:String
}
```

Then open you Core Data model, click on the BookArray entity and make sure that you et its class to BookArray in the attributes inspector:

[image]

2) With such implementation you can rewrite your save function to:

```
 @IBAction func saveOnData(sender: AnyObject) {

    var quoteInputText = quoteInput.text

    var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
    var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    var newQuote = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("BookArray", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! BookArray

    newQuote.myFirstBook = quoteInputText

    context.save(nil)

    println(newQuote)

}
```

3) Change the unwrapping part of your `viewDidLoad` function to:

```
if (bookArray.count != 0){
    var randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(bookArray.count)))
    let bookArrayInstance = bookArray[randomIndex] as! BookArray
    quoteTextField.text = bookArrayInstance.myFirstBook
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested it didn't work. BookArray is an entity on the core data

Comment: You should call bookArrayInstance.myFirstBook. This is the string property which you have.

Comment: Yes, but he is complaining here: `let bookArrayInstance = bookArray[randomIndex] as! BookArray` as Use of undeclared type "BookArray"

Comment: So you didn't define a class for your BookArray?

Comment: How do you the save your user input? You did mention that it works

Comment: "I am using core data to save user input in an array. Until then the code works perfectly" - you are claiming that you are able to save the input correctly. Please show the code snippet which does it

Comment: Ok :) sorry, didn't spot it immediately. Give me 5 minutes I will update my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83263/discussion-between-andriy-gordiychuk-and-skal).

Comment: Hey I made all the changes but while creating a new class popped up two problems
- BookArray has no initializers 
- NSManagedObject is an unknown attribute

Comment: Have you added "import CoreData" above your declaration of BookArray?

Comment: Yes I have, but still

Comment: Ok, now it is displaying an error in the following line: `let bookArrayInstance = bookArray[randomIndex] as! BookArray` and it says: CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'BookArray' for entity 'BookArray'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.
Could not cast value of type 'NSManagedObject_BookArray_' (0x7fafaad71210) to 'Quote_s_Books.BookArray' (0x109d70e50).

Comment: Try including the line "@objc(BookArray)" before the declaration of BookArray class. I have updated my answer to illustrate where to include it. Can you tell me if this is working for you?

Comment: YES! It worked! Thank you. But can you walk me through in what we did? Did I created an array inside an array on what I did before?

Comment: Oh and other thing, how do I access the exactly string that is being displayed on the text field to delete it on the core data?